# How to prevent get/post clash in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm working on a project where I made it so that when a user types a correct password in form field, it will give them the items from the given section.

The main problem i'm having is that to do this I need to capture the request and therefore the route has to be a post method instead of a get as such:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->input('id');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $result = DB::table('scrumboards')->find($id);

        if ($result->key == $password) {
            $scrumboard = $result;
            $items = DB::table('backlogs')->get();
            return view('scrumboard', ['items' => $items, 'scrumboard' => $scrumboard]);
        } else {
            $scrumboard = $result;
            return redirect('home');
        }
    }
```

and the route as such:

```
Route::post('/scrumboard', 'ScrumboardController@index');
```

By doing this, request errors wont work since It wants to redirect back but can't since this is a post method.

Any way I can avoid this clash?

Comment: are you using axios for async data flow between frontend and backend?

Answer (score 3):

Routes can have multiple HTTP verbs. Define your route as

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/scrumboard', 'ScrumboardController@index');
```

to make it available as `GET` and `POST` route.